# No value returned when range of tested values extended

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

I made a program to find Mersenne primes, and it works fine except when I extend the range of tested values above 61.

For example, if I wanted to test 100 numbers to see if they're primes, Idle only shows a blank screen. I can manually put larger values into the middle block, so I don't know if it's just a limitation of lists (too long of a number appended) or 61 is a magical number.

**EDIT**: It appears that the problem might have to do with memory usage, as the program keeps running but never returns anything.

```
Mersenne = []

for i in range(1,61):
    t = (2 ** i) - 1
    Mersenne.append(t)

prime = []
testedValues = [1]

for i in Mersenne:
    passFail = []
    while 1 not in passFail:
        for t in range(2, i):
            if t > (i/testedValues[-1]):
                break
            if i % t == 0:
                passFail.append(1)
                break
            testedValues.append(t)
        if 1 not in passFail:
            prime.append(i)
            break


failed = []
passed = []

for i in Mersenne:
    if i not in prime:
        failed.append(i)
    elif i in prime:
        passed.append(i)

print('Failed: \n', failed,"\n")
print('Passed: \n', passed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your program is that it uses a bad algorithm.  Given enough time it should eventually produce the result for p = 61.  However, that number is 2305843009213693951 and your primality check is inefficient as it's checking every divisor from 2 to n instead of only odd numbers to sqrt(n).  However that's still not sufficient.

The whole point of potential Mersenne primes is we can test their primality more efficiently than using brute force like other odd numbers.  Adding the [Lucas-Lehmer primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test), in place of your original, we get:

```
def Lucas_Lehmer(p):
    s = 4
    M = 2 ** p - 1
    for _ in range(p - 2):
        s = ((s * s) - 2) % M
    return s == 0

Mersenne = [3]
prime = [3]

for i in range(3, 1000):
    t = (2 ** i) - 1
    Mersenne.append(t)

    if Lucas_Lehmer(i):
        prime.append(t)

failed = []

for number in Mersenne:
    if number not in prime:
        failed.append(number)

print('Failed:\n', failed, "\n")
print('Passed:\n', prime)
```

With far superior results, like:

```
Passed:
 [3, 7, 31, 127, 8191, 131071, 524287, 2147483647, 2305843009213693951, 618970019642690137449562111, 162259276829213363391578010288127, 170141183460469231731687303715884105727, 6864797660130609714981900799081393217269435300143305409394463459185543183397656052122559640661454554977296311391480858037121987999716643812574028291115057151, 531137992816767098689588206552468627329593117727031923199444138200403559860852242739162502265229285668889329486246501015346579337652707239409519978766587351943831270835393219031728127]
```